# Adding rows in dataframe based on changing column condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, loops, validation

I have a dataframe that looks like this.

```
          name            Datetime            col_3          col_4        
8       'Name 1'     2017-01-02T00:00:00       160           1600          
9       'Name 1'     2017-01-02T00:00:00       160           1600          
10      'Name 1'     2017-01-03T00:00:00       160           1800          
..                   ...     ...          ...       ...
150     'Name 2'     2004-10-13T00:00:00       160           1600          
151     'Name 2'     2004-10-14T00:00:00       160           1600          
152     'Name 2'     2004-10-15T00:00:00       160           1800       
..                   ...     ...          ...       ...
435     'Name 3'     2009-01-02T00:00:00       160           1600          
436     'Name 3'     2009-01-02T00:00:00       170           1500          
437     'Name 3'     2009-01-03T00:00:00       160           1800
..                   ...     ...          ...       ...
```

Essentially, I want to delete the 'name' column and I want to add a row each time the 'Name-#' field changes, containing only that 'Name-#':

```
                 Datetime            col_2         col_3        
    7            'Name 1'
    8       2017-01-02T00:00:00       160           1600          
    9       2017-01-02T00:00:00       160           1600                   
    ..                ...     ...          ...       ...
    149          'Name 2'
    150     2004-10-13T00:00:00       160           1600          
    151     2004-10-14T00:00:00       160           1600              
    ..                   ...     ...          ...       ...
    435          'Name 3'          
    436     2009-01-02T00:00:00       170           1500          
    437     2009-01-03T00:00:00       160           1800
    ..                ...     ...          ...       ...
```

I know how to add rows once the name column changes, but I need to automate the process of adding in the 'name-#' field in the Datetime column such that different data of the same style can be put though the code. Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: May I ask why you want to add in rows this way? This is usually not advisable and there might be a better way to approach it. For example if you are trying to split the dataframe into tables for each `name`, or if you want to apply some operation to each `name` group, there are other ways to deal with that, such as doing `df.groupby('name')` and working with that object.

Comment: I am trying to load data from one software into another, what I have is what I download from the first software, and the way the second software reads data (in txt. file format) is what I need to obtain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are after is `groupby`

```
df.groupby('name')
```

so you could do

```
for name, dfsub in df.groupby('name'):
    ...
```

This would allow you to work on each group individually

An example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( {
   'Name': ['a','a','a','b','b','b','b','c','c','d','d','d'],
   'B': [5,5,6,7,5,6,6,7,7,6,7,7],
   'C': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
    } )
```

giving a dataframe

```
   Name B   C
0   a   5   1
1   a   5   1
2   a   6   1
3   b   7   1
4   b   5   1
5   b   6   1
6   b   6   1
7   c   7   1
8   c   7   1
9   d   6   1
10  d   7   1
11  d   7   1
```

Now we can just look at the output of a groupby.  groupby in a loop returns two things, the first is the group name, and the second is the subset of the dataframe with the data grouped by it.

```
for name, dfsub in df.groupby('Name'):
    print("Name is :"+name)
    dfsub1 = dfsub.drop(‘Name’, axis=1)
    print(dfsub1)
    print() # new line for clarity
```

and this gives

```
Name is :a
      B  C
0    5  1
1    5  1
2    6  1

Name is :b
    B  C
3   7  1
4   5  1
5   6  1
6   6  1

Name is :c
      B  C
7    7  1
8    7  1

Name is :d
       B  C
9      6  1
10    7  1
11    7  1
```

where you get the name you are dealing with, then the dataframe `dfsub` that contains just the data that you are looking at.

Comment: could you perhaps expand on this? I am a beginner with python and not yet familiar with the groupby function.

Comment: Expanded big man. @knorr976 let me know if you need more

Comment: Hi Paul, not sure that gives me the result I am looking for.. I need the 'Name-#' to be written only once, with the data associated to that name presented below it (i.e. taking out the 'name' column)

Comment: Updated again! Hope this is more to your liking

Comment: Paul - that works much better, thank you! Is there a way to combine these now to make a new dataframe that I can export? Such that the df contains empty rows just with the name, and its corresponding data beneath it?

Comment: No mate that is breaking the way dataframes work...

Comment: Darn okay...and now way to export the groups individually either (name row included)?